# How to import access table to another access table using Python

Tags: python, ms-access-2007, pyodbc

Good Morning.

I'm new to Python and I'm doing a internship at the moment. One part of the script that they want me to make is to import a table from Access database 1 to Access database 2.

I was trying to do something with the 2 following libaries: pyodbc and prettytable. Where I wanted to make a temporary table with prettytable from database 1 and get the values from that and put it in database 2. Where I was hoping that I can put a variable in the SQL. But obvious, that never work. So I'm stuck right now.

Has somebody an idea?

You can read my beautiful code that I use below here:

```
import pyodbc

DBfile = 'C:/Users/stage1/Documents/test.accdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/stage1/Documents/test.accdb;")
cursor = conn.cursor()

DBfile = 'C:/Users/stage1/Documents/test.accdb'
conn2 = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/stage1/Documents/test.accdb;")
cursor2 = conn2.cursor()

SQL = """select naam
FROM naam;"""
for row in cursor.execute(SQL):
    k = row.naam
    print k
    cursor2.execute("""insert into testtable(naam) values (?)""", (k))
    conn2.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()
cursor2.close()
conn2.close()
```

THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED. Thanks to mhawke

Comment: Can you explain exactly what doesn't work?

Comment: k is the variable with the data is from the other table. but if i try this i get the error: there are too few parameters, it is to expected number: 1

what i want is to get data from one database to another database. I figured out that this is not working because i m using sql in the script and there is no k in the database

i m using now only one database but in the future it has to be two different ones.

Comment: You are getting the new error because you are clobbering the `cursor` object inside the loop. If you are iterating over the rows in a cursor object named `cursor` you'll need to use a different cursor object (e.g., one named `cursor2`) to perform the insert.

Comment: thanks, error is now gone. but still not working

edit - the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No comment on what you are doing and why. I don't grok the pretty table stuff, but you need to pass the value of `k` to the execute statement. Change:

```
cursor.execute("""insert into Tableimport(name) values (k)""")
```

to

```
cursor.execute("""insert into Tableimport(name) values (?)""", (k,))
```

The latter is a parameterised query where the `?` placeholder will be replaced with the *value* of `k`.

---

Too much back and forth with comments, and the information provided in the question is not clear enough. So, you can try the following code which checks that the required tables and column exist before attempting any queries. It will display a list of tables and/or columns if anything is not as expected. This is intended to help diagnose the problem, it's not production code.\

```
import pyodbc

DBfile = 'C:/Users/stage1/Documents/test.accdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,    *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/stage1/Documents/test.accdb;")
cursor = conn.cursor()

source_table = 'naam'
dest_table = 'testtable'
column_name = 'naam'

if (cursor.columns(table=source_table, column=column_name).fetchone() and
    cursor.columns(table=dest_table, column=column_name).fetchone()):
    result = cursor.execute("SELECT naam FROM naam")
    for row in result:
        k = row.naam
        print 'Got k: {!r}'.format(k)
        cursor.execute("insert into testtable (naam) values (?)", (k,))
    conn.commit()
else:
    # tables and/or columns missing
    show_tables = show_source_columns = show_dest_columns = False

    if not cursor.tables(table=source_table).fetchone():
        print 'No source table named "{}"'.format(source_table)
        show_tables = True
    elif not cursor.columns(table=source_table, column=column_name).fetchone():
        show_source_columns = True

    if not cursor.tables(table=dest_table).fetchone():
        print 'No destination table named "{}"'.format(source_table)
        show_tables = True
    elif not cursor.columns(table=dest_table, column=column_name).fetchone():
        show_dest_columns = True

    if show_tables:
        print '\n\nAvailable tables are:'
        for row in cursor.tables():
            print row

    if show_source_columns:
        print '\n\nSource table "{}" missing column "{}". Available columns:'.format(source_table, column_name)
        for row in cursor.columns(table=source_table):
            print '{} : {}'.format(row.column_name, row.data_type)

    if show_dest_columns:
        print '\n\nDestination "{}" table missing column "{}". Available columns:'.format(dest_table, column_name)
        for row in cursor.columns(table=dest_table):
            print '{} : {}'.format(row.column_name, row.data_type)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: `?` is the placeholder for pyodbc. Updated answer.

Comment: i was typing the answer why i m doing this, and realise that i want to do something what is not needed at all. So i m feeling really stupid. 

So thanks for the answer and took your time but i was just being really stupid.... 

Thanks anyway

Comment: and yes, i tried ? already. It still not working. Got the same error this time but the parameter is now expected 2.

error: there are too few parameters, it is to expected number: 2

Comment: That's very surprising. Can you post the full and complete traceback in your question (not as a comment - it's too hard to read)?

Comment: i put the traceback into the question.

Comment: The traceback doesn't match the code - line 25? Also the placeholder should be `?`, not `?s`. There are 2 queries in your code, without the correct traceback we don't know which one is failing. Another thing to check is the column and table names - are you sure that they match those in the database?

Comment: i changed what you said but it still not working. I changed the ?, to ?s and  i get a new error. That error is now in my question.

In the script i got some automatic text with who made it. I deleted it now and the next time the row is the correct one.

 i checked all the tables and columns and those are correct

Comment: Try the code that I've added to my answer. It should help diagnose the problem.

Comment: THANKS!!!!

it works perfectly for what i need to do. I was about giving up. I m so sorry that the question was not clear. you are a hero!

Comment: So what was the actual problem?

Comment: i compared what you had with what i had. And i didn't commit the change. So it wasn't saved. I totally forgot about that 

In your script is also 1 fault still. i solved that problem because it was a problem that i also had earlier. 

you can read the solution it in the  comment from Gord Thompson. thats a comment about my question

Comment: i m just very new to phyton and i m not that great yet. So... many thanks helping me out!